# Keyboard short cut in Visual Studio Code to open the keyboard shortcuts panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

My editor says "Ctrl + K Z" will open the shortcut panel...

I have tried various combinations of Ctrl + k + z, ctrl  + k and z together and it never opens.

What exactly does "Ctrl + K Z" mean??? Do I need to press K and Z together? or do K and Z have the same effect and I only need to press one? Nothing I press opens the keybinding window

Answer (score 5):

I think it means you press `Ctrl+k` then release these keys and press the `z`

Answer (score 1):

When you have not changed the keyboard shortcuts previously, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will take you to the keyboard shortcuts panel. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> instead will start the Zen Mode.
According to your second question: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> means you first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (hold it) then press <kbd>K</kbd> (release both) and press <kbd>Z</kbd>.
Here you can find an overview of the default shortcuts:

- [windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)
- [linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)
- [macos](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)